# Linux mint проблема низкое время автономной работы батареи(единственная видеокарта)

Tags: linux, linux-mint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой аппарат `Lenovo-ideapad-320S-13IKB`.

Команда `lspci | grep VGA` выдает только одну единственную видеокарту:
`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)`, т.е. как я понимаю проблема с питанием связанная с переключением дискретной и встроенной видеокарты исключается. В чем искать решение?

Как увеличить период работы в автономном режиме?

Comment: Хмм, на Ваш вопрос сложно ответить. Здесь очень много факторов, начиная от времени работы, которое заявил производитель, и заканчивая процессами запущенными в вашей системе.

Comment: вторая видюха не обязательно будет VGA. почитай без грепа

Comment: Видеокарта: NVIDIA GeForce MX150 согласно спецификации модели.

Comment: @eri без грепа также показывает 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07).

Comment: И ещё 10 строк.

Comment: 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)

Comment: 00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)

Comment: 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth (rev 99)

Comment: 03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation SSD 600P Series (rev 03)

Comment: Это всё что есть.

Comment: В вопросе есть кнопка "редактировать") в комменте это читать тяжело